# Clear App data and cache using phone Gap

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

How can I clear app data programmatically inside PhoneGap application.
Scenario, After user authenticated, if he was not authorized, I need to clear his credentials from app cache.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I am resolved this problem previously by using this

```
`$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function () {
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
};
```

After further search, there is also work around to clear the cache. Is simply by deleting the current cache on success callback

```
delete $scope.variableName (or $rootScope.variableName)
```

Comment: Actually my situation is little different. I am using google oAath api. Once user authenticated if he is not authorized then I should restrict him to proceed further. I am able to restrict him for further proceeding. but when I try to login as different user, Outh window has previous credentials and it is trying to log in as previous user. I need to delete oauth cache in phonegap application. any idea?

Comment: A bit hard without  see your code, but my logic is you can destroy the scope with the success or failure callback

Answer (score 0):

@Zahir Kemang, Thanks for your help.

I solved like below
 `window.open("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout", "_blank", "location=no");`

This clear current user from oAuth cache.